# SQL query for partitioning using two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have an Oracle table called sites where there are multiple records for the same name. For Eg.:

```
 Owner Name          Contact Name            Owner Address  Contact Address    
        A                  A                   XYZ                 SDF
        A                  D                   ABC                 JKL
        B                  E                   QWE                 YUR
        B                  F                   JKL                 SFD
        C                  C                   ZXC                 ASD  
        B                  G                   BNM                 SAD
```

My SQL query should return

```
A1           XYZ
A2           ABC
A3           SDF
B1           QWE
B2           JKL 
B3           BNM
C1           ZXC
C2           ASD
D            JKL
E            YUR
F            SFD
G            SAD
```

Could someone help me write such a query.Ideally, I wouldn't like a number suffix with single records but if  it simplifies the query I could do with that too.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `union` to create what you want:

```
with the_data as ( 
  select owner_name as name, owner_address as address
    from my_table
   union all
  select contact_name as name, contact_address as address
    from my_table
         )
select name 
        || case when count(*) over ( partition by name ) = 1 then ''
                else to_char(row_number() over ( partition by name 
                                                     order by address ))
           end
     , address
  from the_data
```

If you only want distinct address, contact combinations change the `union all` to `union`. [Here it is in SQL Fiddle form](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/07a2d/5).

Answer (score 0):

Do partition on Owner Name   column in first query -> query 1
Do partition on Contact Name  column in second query -> query 2

Do Union query 1 & query 2